# If $\int_{\Omega\cap B_R}|f|\,dx\leq K R^n$ for some constant $K$, does $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth bounded domain. Assume that for a measurable function $f$, there exists a constant $K>0$ such that
$$
\int_{\Omega\cap B_R}|f|\,dx\leq K R^n,
$$
where $B_R$ is a ball. My question is that how to prove $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. If $f$ is continuous, then this proposition is trivial. For general $f$, I don't know how to prove it. Actually, I know there exists a set sequence $\{\Omega_n\}$ such that $|f(x)|>n$ in $\Omega_n$. But since $f$ is not continuous and $\Omega_n$ is just measurable, we can't find a ball $B_n\subset\Omega_n$ (actually I'm not sure about this, maybe we can let $\Omega_n$ be open but I don't know how to do it), so we can't get a contradiction.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some help. Thanks!

Comment: If your inequality holds for all $R$, then appying [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) to $|f|\chi_{\Omega}$ may help.

Comment: oh thank you!!!  This really helps me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $f$ by $0$ off the domain $\Omega$ (neither smoothness nor boundedness is required). Then you have $$\frac 1{|B_R|} \int_{B_R} |f| \, dx \le \frac K{\omega_n}$$ where $\omega_n$ is the $n$-volume of the unit ball. Since this holds for every ball, you have that
$$\limsup_{R \to 0^+} \frac 1{|B_R(x)|} \int_{B_R(x)} |f| \, dx \le \frac K{\omega_n}$$ for *every* $x \in \mathbf R^n$. According to the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem you must have $$|f(x)| \le \frac K{\omega_n}$$ for almost every $x \in \mathbf R^n$.

Comment: Oh my, this theorem is very powerful! Thanks for your help!!!